# How do I Install OpenIDConnect Nuget Package with Dependency on "DNX 4.5.1"

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package, openid-connect

Trying to install the [OpenIDConnect](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/) Nuget package to my project, which was targeting `.NET Framework 4.5`.  That failed, with the error:

> *Could not install package
>   '`Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication.OpenIdConnect 1.0.0-rc1-final`'. You
>   are trying to install this package into a project that targets
>   '`.NETFramework,Version=v4.5`', but the package does not contain any
>   assembly references or content files that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.*

So I look at the dependencies for the package, and see that "DNX 4.5.1" is listed:

> ## Dependencies
>
> **DNX 4.5.1**
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) 
>    Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 2.0.0-rc1-211161024)
>
> **DNXCore 5.0**
>
> Microsoft.AspNet.Authentication (>= 1.0.0-rc1-final) 
>   Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect (>= 2.0.0-rc1-211161024)
>   System.Net.Http (>= 4.0.1-beta-23516)

... so I assumed that `DNX` is a useless abbreviation of ".NET" - who knows, maybe the field doesn't accept a '**.**' in the field, so they had to come up with something else.  No worries, I'll just upgrade my project to `.NET Framework 4.5.1` and try again.

... but that didn't work.  I get the same error, but the error has the 4.5.1 version number.

I looked at the ["install other frameworks" page](https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/visual-studio-sdks) and I don't see any "DNX" frameworks listed there.

1. What am I doing wrong?
2. What's with the "DNX" business?

Comment: You're using stuff from the early days of netstandard. It's frought with danger. Target 4.6 and try again.

Comment: @Will nope, same issue with 4.6 and 4.7.2

Comment: Okay, so that package is meant to work against ASP.NET 5, which is now known as ASP.NET Core. Are you actually writing an ASP.NET 5 application? Or did you reverse engineer something you needed and found it in that package?

Comment: @Will, so what's the DNX 4.5.1 dependency?  I'm trying to use OpenIDConnect in a .NET Framework MVC 5.2.4 project.  This was a way I thought I could make that happen.

Comment: All that DNX stuff came out during the birth of .NET Core. It's all been trashed since Core 1 and netstandard 1 were released. You're way out in the weeds, and all I have is a gallon of gasoline and a book of matches to help you with. My answer is burn it all down and move to Core 2, but I don't know if you're stuck in the twilight zone or just a victim of the wrong tutorial.

Comment: I've subsequently found that previous versions - in the `microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect` nuget package - work just fine in my project, so I'm going with that.  I'll probably delete this question tomorrow, b/c I don't see how it could be helpful.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I Install OpenIDConnect Nuget Package with Dependency on “DNX 4.5.1”

Just like Will said, this nuget package came out during the birth of .NET Core and you can also find this this nuget package is a just a pre-release version, microsoft has not officially released it. It has not been updated since 11/18/2015. Obviously,The NuGet team deprecated this package.

[image]

To resolve this issue, you can use the package `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect` instead of it.

Get it from: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect/2.1.0-preview1-final

Hope this helps.

Comment: I am not developing a .NET core project.  My project is in .NET Framework 4.7.2 - the package installs just fine, but I'd prefer to get this figured out without having to jump to another framework's implementation.  I'm currently attempting to get the `microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect` package to get the job done.  Any thoughts?

Comment: @ScottBaker, Yes, if you are using .NET Framework 4.7.2, the nuget package `microsoft.owin.security.openidconnect` is a good choose.